# How to make Bash commands recognize "-" as part of the filename and not an option?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

> How to make Bash commands recognize "-" as part of the filename and not an option?

I want to hexdump the contents of a file called `-9` in Bash. Therefore, I use the following command:

```
hexdump -C \-9
```

Here, I try to escape `-` like I'd escape a space .

But, `hexdump` gives the following error:

```
hexdump: invalid option -- '9'
```

I.e., `hexdump` interprets the filename as an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to use `--` to mark the end of the options :

```
$ echo "test" > -9   # in this case it can't be understood as an option, no problem
$ hexdump -C -- -9   # -- marks the end of the options, so the -9 is understood as a filename
00000000  74 65 73 74 0a                                    |test.|
00000005
```

This is a particularity of `getopt`, as documented in [its man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt).

Comment: Thank you @Aaron - this works and solved my problem. Is this common Bash syntax? Do you know if it works for all POSIX shells?

Comment: Ahh, just saw your `getopt` comment. I guess your point is that most commands use `getopt` to parse arguments?

Comment: `--` is not shell-specific, it is just an argument that many programs understand to mean "options end here".

Comment: @Shuzheng just edited with the answer to your question ;) The use of `getopt` is quite widespread but clearly not guaranteed ; the linked duplicate question gives a good generic answer, prefixing the filename with `./`